# Python ¿En un dataframe, con una columna con fechas dd/mm/aaaa, como puedo reemplazar cada celda por solo el mes?

Tags: python, dataframe

tengo un dataframe

```
0   2020-07-15  86  190.08  MAHNRG
1   2020-08-06  79  1530.00 MAHNRG
2   2020-11-02  80  264.47  MAHNRG
3   2020-11-12  76  548.40  MAHNRG
4   2020-11-12  76  581.80  MAHNRG
```

Cómo puedo reemplazar la columna de fechas por solo el nombre del mes, que quede

```
0   Julio       86  190.08  MAHNRG
1   Agosto      79  1530.00 MAHNRG
2   Noviembre   80  264.47  MAHNRG
3   Noviembre   76  548.40  MAHNRG
4   Noviembre   76  581.80  MAHNRG
```

Comment: Por favor, muestra algo de código de lo que has intentado por ahora para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Pude solucionar mi duda de la siguiente forma

primero importando la librería datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Luego, como la segunda columna de mi dataframe es de tipo Timestamp entonces se puede extraer el mes usando

```
df["Fecha documento"][i].strftime("%b") #esto extrae solo el mes de la fecha
```